# Is it possible to store a PHP imap stream as a session variable?

Tags: php, email, imap

I have the following piece of code that opens an imap stream:

```
<?php
    session_name('mysession');
    session_start();

    $mailbox = "{my_mailbox_name}";

    $username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
    $password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
    if(isset($username) && isset($password)){
        if($_SESSION['imapStream'] = imap_open($mailbox,$username,$password)){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['imapStream'] = null;
        }
    }
    $errorArray = imap_errors();
    header("Location: ./");
    exit;
?>
```

However, whenever I attempt to use the $_SESSION['imapStream'] variable somewhere else in my code, I get errors like so:

```
Warning: imap_num_msg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /www/...

Warning: imap_fetch_overview() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /www/...

Warning: imap_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /www/...
```

I have tried serializing and unserializing the variable, but that doesn't work either. Any advice?

EDIT: Added an example of how I am using this in my other code:

```
<?php
    session_name('mysession');
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && isset($_SESSION['imapStream'])){
        $number_of_messages = imap_num_msg($_SESSION['imapStream']);
        $msgArray = imap_fetch_overview($_SESSION['imapStream'], "1:{$number_of_messages}");
        imap_close($_SESSION['imapStream']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: No, you cannot serialize a resource

Comment: no, you cannot store resources in the session

Comment: Well that stinks. Any ideas how I can pass this around?

Comment: Resources can't be serialize.... if you need to serialize (or store in session) a class instance that has a resource property, then you need to use the __sleep and __wakeup magic methods to disconnect and reconnect that resource - see [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep)

Comment: Why would you want to? Persist the credentials instead and call `imap_open` again when you need to.

Comment: @Steve It just seemed like a better idea to pass around the stream instead of having to open a new one every time.

Comment: For this to work your server would have to keep a connection open for every user indefinitely, because a previously logged in user might pop up at any time.

Comment: @Steve Wouldn't the connection automatically close when the session ended?

Comment: Well session lifetime can be set to years. Anyway, this is all academic, because php simply doesnt allow you to serialize a resource (after all, session data is just plain text in a regular text file on the server)